# Getting current timestamp in DB2 query in IST timezone

Tags: sql, db2

I have a query wherein I would wish to retrieve the current timestamp in **IST** timezone. Now since my database(**DB2**) server is located in **UK (i.e. BST timezone)**: a simple query as below to get the same would retrieve the time in BST.

`Select current timezone from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1`

Now, I can convert this to IST timezone by adding **4 hours and 30 minutes** to the query, such as:

`Select current timezone + 4 Hours + 30 minutes from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1`

which would fetch me the correct result. However, the issue starts during Daylight Saving Time, when the difference would be **5 hours and 30 minutes**.

Hence, this would require me to change the query manually.

So, is there a way, such as a function or anything else in **db2** that would dynamically perform these operations and give me the result in IST timezone.

I have visited every link that I could find but nothing works. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You may write a simple java function (using [java.util.TimeZone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getOffset(long)) class) accepting a time zone name and returning a dec(6) time duration. The corresponding call would be: `timestamp_value - current timezone + get_timezone(‘IST’)`.

Answer (score 0):

In Db2 11.5 you can use the `TIMEZONE` function.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r_sf_timezone.html

```
values (current timestamp, TIMEZONE(current_timestamp, 'Europe/London', 'IST') )

1                          2                         
-------------------------- --------------------------
2019-09-06-22.28.52.760304 2019-09-07-02.58.52.760304

  1 record(s) selected.
```

or equally

```
values (current timestamp, TIMEZONE(current_timestamp - current timezone, 'UTC', 'IST') )

1                          2                         
-------------------------- --------------------------
2019-09-06-22.29.53.252608 2019-09-07-02.59.53.252608

  1 record(s) selected.
```